# How to make rotated div reduce in height for surrounding elements?

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a kind of a stack of notifications going from top to bottom one under another.
On the images below there are 3 notifications shown. When I click on the close button, it applies a class `collapsed` to the respective box and it should make it rotate 90deg x axis as well as reduce its height to 0 with the css3 transition.

To show my issue I have put middle box rotation to 45 degrees. As you can see, the box looks like it's still the same height as when it was not rotated, so boxes on on the top and on the bottom still stay on their positions. I want them to move according to the rotating degree.

How can I make it properly?

[image: Notifications]

Comment: height = cosine(angle of rotation) with some scripting?

Comment: We need to see the code